# Помогите разобраться с адаптером для списка recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня в приложении есть список построенный на основе RecyclerView и адаптера, и я не могу понять как все это работает и почему у меня лезут ошибки. Этот список используется для отображения списка сообщений (входящие, исходящие, черновики). Я сделал этот список по примеру и как результат не все понятно. Суть работы со списком такая: при получении списка сообщений я их отображаю (тут все нормально работает вроде), дальше у меня есть слушатель длительного и короткого нажатия на элемент списка, при коротком нажатии у меня открывается просмотр сообщения, а при длительном у меня делается переход в режим редактирования, когда некоторые части у элемента списка скрываются а некоторые наоборот появляются, и так же в активити где висит этот список у меня появляется кнопка. Появляется чекбокс у каждого элемента списка при выборе которого в массив добавляется id сообщения для удаления нескольких сообщений (тут вроде нет проблем, но я не уверен). И наконец, где у меня реально заметные проблемы - я пытаюсь внедрить выделение всех элементов списка для того чтобы удалить сразу все сообщения, например входящие. Для того чтобы выделить сразу все сообщения я нажимаю на отдельно стоящий чекбокс и у меня список переходит в режим редактирования и все чекбоксы выделены (но срабатывает выделение всех чеков со второго раза почему-то). Но все элементы списка например мы забросили в массив и дальше нажимаем на кнопку для их удаления, запрос шлется все нормально, и сообщения удаляются но дальше приложение слетает с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.test_login/com.example.developer_4.test_login.Screens.MessageCenter}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
```

ошибка указывает на строку с комментом:

```
CheckBox checkBox = rootView.findViewById(R.id.choose_all);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                if (checked) {
                    ListAdapter.editMode = true;
                    ListAdapter.checkAlll = false;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // эта строка
                }
                if (!checked) {
                    ListAdapter.editMode = false;
                    ListAdapter.checkAlll = true;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

и вот собственно весь адаптер:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.SenderHolder> {

    private Integer type;
    private ArrayList<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;
    public static boolean editMode;
    public static boolean checkAlll;
    public static boolean clearAllCheck;
    private StateListener stateListener;
    private static HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id";
    private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id";
    private static final String keyDraftMessageId = "draft_message_id";

    ListAdapter(ArrayList<Message> messageList, Context ctx, int type) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.type = type;
    }

    void setListener(StateListener listener) {
        this.stateListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SenderHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new SenderHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SenderHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);
        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        boolean attachment = message.isAttachment();
        Integer new_one = message.getNewField();

        if (getItemCount() > 0) {
            if (checkAlll) {
                checkAll();
                stateListener.check(1);
            }
            if (!checkAlll) {
                stateListener.check(0);
            }
        } else {
            editMode = false;
            checkAlll = false;
            stateListener.check(0);
        }

        if (editMode) {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            stateListener.check(1);

        } else {
            stateListener.check(0);
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (attachment) {
                holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
                break;
        }

        if (new_one == 1 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message.getSender_name())) {
            holder.tvSubject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.tvDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.tvFrom.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());


        DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
        String isoString = message.getDate();
        try {
            Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
            holder.tvDate.setText(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                switch (type) {
                    case 0:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyOutboundMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyIncomingMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyDraftMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                }

                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (message.isCan_delete()) {
                    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                setEditMode();
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (set.contains(message.getId())) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    set.add(message.getId());
                } else {
                    set.remove(message.getId());
                    if (getChecked().isEmpty()) {
                        editMode = false;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                /*List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
                Toast.makeText(ctx, list.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            }
        });
    }


    private void setEditMode() {
        if (!editMode) {
            editMode = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void checkAll() {
        for (Message message : messageList) {
            set.add(message.getId());
        }
    }


    public static HashSet<Integer> getChecked() {
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class SenderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;
        final ImageView attachIV;
        final CheckBox checkBox;

        SenderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            attachIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clip);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_item);
        }
    }
}
```

вероятнее всего адаптер создан не очень правильно, или вообще неправильно, принцип работы адаптера мне вроде как понятен, но если бы все было понятно как нужно, то я бы сам решил эту проблему. Если я правильно понял из моего изучения данного вопроса, то функция `onBindViewHolder` используется для построения одного отдельного элемента списка, но вот как дальше применить эти знания я не представляю.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь и ценные советы по решению этой проблемы.

### UPDATE

вот код моего фрагмента со списком:

```
public class MessageList extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    Integer type, count;
    ImageView ivPicture;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    Boolean check;
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_received, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            type = bundle.getInt("type1");
        }
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_res);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        getMessages(type);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);

        CheckBox checkBox = rootView.findViewById(R.id.choose_all);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                if (checked) {
                    ListAdapter.editMode = true;
                    ListAdapter.checkAlll = true;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if (!checked) {
                    ListAdapter.editMode = false;
                    ListAdapter.checkAlll = false;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });


        linearLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_layout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_2);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        getMessages(type);
    }


    public void getMessages(final int type) {
        sp = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("access_token", 0);
        String a_token = sp.getString("access_token", "");
        APIService mAPIService = apiService();
        mAPIService.get_list_of_messages("Bearer " + a_token, type, 1).enqueue(new Callback<MessageArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MessageArray> call, @NonNull final Response<MessageArray> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    count = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getCount();
                    if (count > 0) {

                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
                        adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        ((ListAdapter) adapter).setListener((MessageCenter) getActivity());

                    } else if (count == 0) {
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ivPicture = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.ivNoMess);
                        ivPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("access_token_expired")) {
                            updateToken();
                        } else if (errorBody.string().contains("invalid_token")) {
                            updateToken();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MessageArray> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void updateToken() {

    }


    public void logOut() {

    }


    public APIService apiService() {

    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли где-то проинициализировать ссылку на адаптер (ошибка, собственно об этом и говорит). И избавьтесь в конце концов от статических обращений к адаптеру -  потому что статик поля существуют и хранят значения не зависимо от экземпляров их классов и жизненных циклов активностей и фрагментов - из-за этого могут быть недоразумения и утечки памяти.

Comment: @woesss, я знаю что будут проблемы с статическими полями, но я по другому не могу менять значение этих переменных извне

Comment: Можете - у Вас же есть ссылка на адаптер. Только нужно разобраться почему ей не присвоено значение на момент вызова `onCheckedChanged`

Comment: а где это можно найти? у меня есть такая строка - `adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);` я так понимаю что это ссылка на этот адаптер, но вот что дальше делать я не очень понимаю

Comment: В каком методе и классе эта строка, вызывается ли этот метод, доступна ли та ссылка (является ли той же самой, а не одноимённой) в обработчике чекбокса?. Всё это проверяйте. И смените в вопросе код адаптера на код класса, где всё это происходит.

Comment: @woesss, обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: А точно в этом фрагменте ошибка происходит?

Comment: у меня он один, на данный момент после того как вставил ту строку которую приводил ранее, вроде как падений приложения нету, но это для меня как-то странно, при том что я не смог изменить все поля на нестатик и работать с ними в таком режиме